# Reorder list view dropdown

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to apply a custom order to the "Select A View" drop down and left navigation menu that appears on list pages in Sharepoint 2007? 
For example we have All Views, January, February, ... December, but sharepoint sorts them alphabetically.  I need these to sort in chronologic order.  Is this possible Out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such OOTB setting for that.For workaround, maybe you could rename your view and add numerical value in front of the view, for example: 01 January, 02 February etc..

I hope it will help you to solve that problem